# How can I make a motorcycle CDI (capacitor discharge ignition) using a power MOSFET?

Tags: capacitor

Is there any way to make a CDI using only power mosfets.

I've searched everywhere on the internet but couldn`t find any circuit.

Comment: Uhm, plenty circuits to be found when you Google "capacitor discharge ignition circuit" and then press the **Images** tab. But **only** using power MOSFETs, no, not possible, a transformer is also needed.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a CDI utilizing FETs.

Answer (score 1):

No.

It takes more than a MOSFET to control phase and timing of ignition pulses.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00001980C.pdf

http://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en575368#utm_source=MicroSolutions&utm_medium=Link&utm_term=FY17Q1&utm_content=MCU8&utm_campaign=Article

But here are primitive ways to replace the points with a transistor or MOSFET or IGBT but not gauranteed to improve performance.

https://www.rmcybernetics.com/science/diy-devices/diy-ignition-coil-driver

[image]